# How to find 3 x 3 matrix inverses

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Is there a way of finding the inverse of a $3 \times 3$ matrix without forming an augmented matrix with the identity matrix? Also, is there a quick way of checking that a  $3 \times 3$ matrix's inverse exists, without trying to compute it? Thanks.

Comment: Yes I do. I also know how to find determinants of 3x3 matrices using the 'minors'. Is it true that for a 3x3 matrix to have an inverse, its determinant must be non zero?

Comment: $A$ is invertible $\iff$ $\det A\ne 0$.

Comment: @joe S Ya it must be true. For a matrix having zero determinant inverse dosn't exist such a matrices are called singular matrix.

Answer (score 9):

Starting with a $3\times 3$ matrix
$$
A=\left(\begin{matrix}
a & b & c \\
d & e & f \\
g & h & i
\end{matrix}\right)
$$
**1. Check that the matrix is invertible.** First we need to check that we can actually invert the matrix. This amounts to showing that its determinant is non-zero.
$$
\det A=a\det\left(\begin{matrix}e & f \\ h & i\end{matrix}\right)-b\det\left(\begin{matrix}d & f \\ g & i\end{matrix}\right)+c\det\left(\begin{matrix}d & e \\ g & h\end{matrix}\right)
$$
**2. Find the cofactors of the matrix.** For each of the $(i,j)$-th entries of the matrix $A$, we denote the cofactor $C_{ij}$ by $(-1)^{i+j}M_{ij}$, where $M_{ij}$ is the determinant of the $2\times 2$ matrix obtained from $A$ by removing the $i$-th row and the $j$-th column. For example
$$
M_{23}=\det\left(\begin{matrix}
a & b & - \\
- & - & - \\
g & h & -
\end{matrix}\right)
=\det\left(\begin{matrix}a & b \\ g & h\end{matrix}\right)=ah-bg
$$
So $C_{23}=(-1)^{2+3}(ah-bg)=bg-ah$.

**3. Find the adjugate matrix.** After finding all the cofactors, the adjugate of $A$ is
$$
\text{adj }A=\left(\begin{matrix}
C_{11} & C_{12} & C_{13} \\
C_{21} & C_{22} & C_{23} \\
C_{31} & C_{32} & C_{33}
\end{matrix}\right)^T=\left(\begin{matrix}
C_{11} & C_{21} & C_{31} \\
C_{12} & C_{22} & C_{32} \\
C_{13} & C_{23} & C_{33}
\end{matrix}\right)
$$
That is you make a matrix out of the cofactors, and then you transpose the matrix.

**4. We're done!** Finally, we can can write the inverse as
$$
A^{-1}=\frac{1}{\det A}\text{adj }A
$$

Answer (score 3):

**Steps to find Inverse**

**1.** Find determinant of $3\times 3$ Matrix

**2.** Find minor

**3.** Find Cofactor

**4.** Find Adjoint

**5.** Replace results in below formula

$A^{-1} = \frac{1}{\det(A)} adj(A)$

As you are unaware of these terms so let me first define it for you.

If A is a square matrix, $(3\times 3)$ for example, then the minor of entry $a_{ij}$ , denoted by $A_{ij}$  is defined to be the determinant of the submatrix that remains after the $i$th row and $j$th column are deleted from A. The number $(-1)^{i+j} A_{ij}$, denotd by $C_{ij}$ and is called the cofactor of entry $a_{ij}$.

You need to form cofactor matrix given as

$C   = \left(
  \begin{array}{ccc}
    C_{11} & C_{12} & C_{13} \\
    C_{21} & C_{22} &  C_{23} \\
   C_{31}  & C_{32} & C_{33} \\
  \end{array}
\right)$

To find the adjoint of a matrix denoted by $adj(A)$, just transpose the cofactor
matrix.

[This link will help you to understand this](http://www.utdallas.edu/dept/abp/PDF_Files/LinearAlgebra_Folder/Cofactors.pdf)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm not sure what the cofactor or adjoint is. Could you please explain those? Thanks again

Comment: @JoeS Ya sure . I will edit it.

Answer (score 1):

In order to check invertibility, you compute a determinant. If it's zero, the matrix is not invertible.

Check here [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix), section "Analytic solution".